# Problem to find 0 values when Query with Term/Range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a number field on my index which works as a count and the problem is when I try to query that field equals 0, I don't get any value.

I'm sure about possible values in the Index because If I execute the query without any filter it returns at least 50 occurrences where the field equals 0.

I tried with term:

```
GET contacts/_search
  {
    "query": { 
      "term": {
        "investmentsCount": {
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

or using range

```
GET contacts/_search
  {
    "query": { 
      "range": {
        "investmentsCount": {
          "lte": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Also, I tried with range with "lt": 1 and it didn't return anything. Even if I try less_than < 2, I receive just the ones with count = 1 but not the 0 ones. Any tips?

Sample Document:

```
GET contacts/_search
  {
    "query": { 
      "term": {
        "investmentsCount": {
          "value": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }

  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 432,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "contacts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "1",
          "accountId" : "1",
          "committed" : 7500000,          
          "contributed" : 7500000,
          "investedMax" : "2020-03-18T01:53:31.160Z",
          "investedMin" : "2020-03-18T01:53:31.160Z",
          "investmentsCount" : 1,
          "status" : "ACTIVE",
          "updated" : "2020-03-18T01:43:39.854Z",
          "userId" : "1",
          "withdrawnMax" : "2020-03-18T01:53:58.092Z",
          "withdrawnMin" : "2020-03-18T01:53:58.092Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a sample document,  could be issue of spelling of fieldname

Comment: I included in the answer, a result when I query by 1 investmentsCount

Comment: There is specifically  0 value or null?

Comment: No, when I query without a filter I saw them just as `"investmentsCount" : 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run a aggregate query to see the unique values of investmentsCount. In most probability, I am guessing that field is not being populated with value 0, in which case, you will need to correct your ingestion process.

Comment: I think you are right, it didn't return the key = 0 in the aggregation response

Comment: Great. So correct your ingestion process and you should all set. Pls dont forget to mark the answer :)